# Prism region ordering using generic viewmodel without ViewSortHintAttribute

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a PRISM region:

```
<ItemsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.AdministrationCommandsRegion}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Which I am adding view models to using the region manager:

```
_regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.AdministrationCommandsRegion].Add(new CommandViewModel("User Management", new DelegateCommand(RequestNavigate));
```

`CommandViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class CommandViewModel
{
    public CommandViewModel(string displayName, ICommand command)
    {
        if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        DisplayName = displayName;
        Command = command;
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; private set; }
}
```

I want to specify the ordering of the `CommandViewModels` in the region but I can't find a way to specify the `ViewSortHint` attribute for the `CommandViewModel` so that it is different for each instance. Is there any way that I can pass the ViewSortHint into the constructor for the `CommandViewModel` instead of relying on attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ViewSortHint` attribute, you could solve the sort issue by using the `SortComparison` Region's property.

The `SortComparison` property can be set to a `Comparison<object>` delegate method in order to sort the **ViewModels**.

```
this._regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].SortComparison = CompareViewModels;
```

This comparison can be made on a `SortIndex` property implementing for example, an `ISortable` interface on the related **ViewModels**. Therefore, the delegate method would compare the `ISortable` `SortIndex` property:

```
private static int CompareViewModels(object x, object y)
{
  ISortable xSortable = (ISortable) x;
  ISortable ySortable = (ISortable) y;
  return xSortable.SortIndex.CompareTo(ySortable.SortIndex);
}
```

Finally, you can pass the `SortIndex` value to the `ViewModel` contructor and set the `ISortable` property for each instance.

You can find more information in the following Prism Guide chapter:

- [Composing the User Interface: Ordering Views in a Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.